# Set session variable inside plugin model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, session-variables

So I'd like to set/get a session variable from inside a plugin model that I've included to my project.  I tried making a method (one getter one setter) inside the application_controller.rb but this did not work.  Where can I make getter/setter methods so that a plugin model has access to them?

Answer (score 0):

Create a module in the lib folder in the directory.